# How to apply PowerMockito on RestTemplate

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

In my code i have New operator for RestTemplate. Let me know how to apply Powermockito on below RestTemplate.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response =  new RestTemplate().exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PowerMockito.whenNew` and return mock object using `mock`

See [example](https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-new-object-creation-powermock/) with `PowerMockDemo` class and `Point` new operator instead `RestTemplate`

> annotate unit test with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` telling JUnit to use PowerMock runner and with `@PrepareForTest(PowerMockDemo.class)` telling PowerMock to get inside `PowerMockDemo` class and prepare it for mocking. Mocking is done with `PowerMockito.whenNew(Point.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockPoint)`. It tells PowerMock when a new object from class `Point` is instantiated with whatever arguments to return `mockPoint` instead. It is possible to return different objects based on different arguments Point is created with `withArguments()` method

Comment: I've written Mockito condition like below , but its not working , Can you help me on it ..    PowerMockito.whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockPoint);